# Fat Free Framework 3.0 and multiple files

Tags: fat-free-framework

I finished a simple project with F3 (fat free framework) 2.0 and everything worked great. Now I'm starting a new project and I see it's been changed quite a bit. I've created a simple basic test and just keep hitting error's and weirdness. I'm no expert with F3 and yes I've read the documentation and yes of course I probably missed something. Hoping someone can help me. Here's my example that fails:

Start with my config file

### config.cfg

```
cfgDbConnection="mysql:host=localhost;port=8889;dbname=test";
cfgDbUser="root"
cfgDbPassword="123456"
cfgCache=true
```

//...etc

The starting point

### index.php

```
$f3=require('lib/base.php');
$f3->set('UI','ui/');
$f3->set('AUTOLOAD', 'classes/'); // this folder contains class objects for the project

$f3->config('config.cfg');
$f3->set('CACHE', $f3->get('cfgCache'));
$f3->set('DEBUG',3); 

$db = new DB\SQL(
    $f3->get('cfgDbConnection'),
    $f3->get('cfgDbUser'),
    $f3->get('cfgDbPassword')
);
$f3->set('DB',$db);

require_once("menuRoutes.php");
$f3->run();
```

The first of 5 php files for routing

### menuRoutes.php

```
<?php
$f3->route('GET /', function() use ($f3){
    AuthManager::authenticateSession($f3); // checks if user is logged in /classes/AutManager.php 
    echo View::instance()->render('landing.htm');
});
```

### landing.htm

```
<include href="mainHeaderBar.htm"/> (this has css & js loads)
general html.......
<include href="mainFooterBar.htm"/> (other jquery scripts)
```

At this point page loads the general html, CSS and JS scripts are not loading because the includes are not loading, they are being ignored.......?

PHP Log shows:

```
HTTP 405 (HEAD /)
/Users/home/Documents/My Projects/testApp/web/index.php:39 Base->run()
ob_clean(): failed to delete buffer. No buffer to delete
/Users/home/Documents/My Projects/testApp/web/lib/base.php:859 ob_clean()
/Users/home/Documents/My Projects/testApp/web/lib/base.php:1118 Base->error(405)
/Users/home/Documents/My Projects/testApp/web/index.php:39 Base->run()
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message 'ob_clean(): failed to delete buffer. No buffer to delete' in /Users/home/Documents/My Projects/testApp/web/lib/base.php:1391
```

Thanks for the help/advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your include Tags are Not being rendered, because you're not using the template class... Try

```
echo Template::instance()->render('landing.htm');
```

Instead of View

Comment: I made the change and now see:Undefined offset: 0
/Users/...My Projects/test/web/lib/base.php:136 Base->{closure}(8,'Undefined offset: 0','/Users/.../My Projects/test/web/lib/base.php',136,array('key'=>NULL,'add'=>false,'parts'=>array()))
/Users/..../My Projects/test/web/lib/base.php:178 Base->ref(NULL,false)
/Users/.../My Projects/test/web/classes/AuthManager.php:20 Base->exists(NULL)
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1077936128 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 130968 bytes) in /Users/.../My Projects/test/web/lib/base.php on line 438

Comment: well,... it's not easy to remote debug with just that tiny bit of information. Possibly the answer was told by that "Undefined offset: 0" line.. maybe you try to use undefined vars in your template. that's not possible in v3 anymore.. add <check> condition if that var exists in template or set a default value in your controller. If you want more help, please show us some more of your code / sub-templates etc... you can also join us on IRC @ freenode #fatfree

Comment: Doh, simple array indexing issue. Changed that and now it works just fine. Thanks for your efforts :-)